# Why does Kasumigaoka call Tomoya "Mr. Ethical"?

Tags: saenai-heroine-no-sodatekata

In *Saekano: How to Raise a Boring Girlfriend*, Kasumigaoka always calls Tomoya "Mr. Ethical" (倫理{りんり}君{くん}).

Where did this come from? Is it explained at some point in the original source material?

Feel free to spoil it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the [Saekano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saekano:_How_to_Raise_a_Boring_Girlfriend#Main_characters) wiki-page in the description for Utaha:

> She used to call Tomoya Tomoya-kun (倫也君) but now she calls him Rinri-kun (倫理君). She began to call him by the nickname Rinri-kun when he flatly rejected her suggestion that he read the last volume of Koisuru Metronome before it is published.

"Rinri-kun" being "Mr. Ethical."

In other words, Tomoya is called Mr. Ethical by Utaha due to his ethical behavior, in this case, with how he decided to wait until the release of the last book — just as every other fan/reader has to wait — in order to enjoy the novel. It'd be unfair for him to get first dibs on reading it before everyone else.

Comment: I think the fact that both names share the first kanji should have some influence on the name choice.

Comment: Entirely possible as well, however I can't act as a good source on that since I am not familiar with Japanese. Also the first and last symbols are the same: 倫( 也 )君 and 倫( 理 )君 with only the middle symbol being different. So at the same time, it could be Utaha's sense of humor conveyed here as well.

Comment: The last one the "kun" honorific. So that's bound to be the same :P

Comment: I told you I didn't understand Japanese. :)