# Why does Kasumigaoka get attracted to Tomoya?

Tags: saenai-heroine-no-sodatekata

In Saekano: How to Raise a Boring Girlfriend,

I don't understand how she is attracted to him? well she loves to flirt with him and make the other girls jealous on purpose.

Feel free to spoil it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Episodes 4 and 6 we find out about the history between Utaha and Tomoya. Tomoya was a superfan of Utaha's book series, and wrote a ton of praise for it on his blog. Utaha was impressed with how thorough his knowledge of her books was, and developed tremendous respect for his opinion, to the point that she tried to give him her unfinished draft. He refused on principle, which led her to [start calling him "Rinri-kun"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19170/7579).

As she developed respect for Tomoya, Utaha's feelings also deepened into something like love. She often seems unsure herself whether she loves him, though, and possibly she's afraid of being rejected as she was when she asked him for feedback on her partially finished novel, so she always makes light of it and flirts with him playfully so she can back out if she needs to. The [upcoming sequel](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-03-17/saekano-tv-anime-sequel-to-premiere-on-noitamina-in-april-2017/.99908) will probably expand on Utaha and Tomoya's relationship.

Comment: thank you for the feedback...when is the sequel coming? I really like the series...damn I'm envious of tomoya cause he is surrounded with pretty girls

Comment: @JustinX The article I linked says the sequel will start airing April 2017.